# How to use basic http authentication on Windows rt- Visual Studio 2012 - C#

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, basic-authentication

how can i use **basic http Authentication** for a HTTPS URL Windows 8 Store App.
I am using Visual Studio 2012, C# and XAML.

Is there any point to keep attention when i use an HTTPS URL?

i have tried these following methods:

**#1**:  **###Code is UPDATED - Final running solution**

```
        private async void HttpClientCall(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name + ": HTTPCLientCall entered");

        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess: " + NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess);

        //use this, for checking the network connectivity
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GetIsNetworkAvailable: " + System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable());

        //var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("GetIsNetworkAvailable: " + System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable());
        //msg.ShowAsync();


        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();


        // Assign the authentication headers
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = CreateBasicHeader("username", "password");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization: " + httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization);


        // Call out to the site
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://URLHere");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("response: " + response);
        string responseAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("response string:" + responseAsString);

        //WebViewP.Source = new Uri("https://URLHere");
    }




    public AuthenticationHeaderValue CreateBasicHeader(string username, string password)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password);

        String logindata = (username + ":" + password);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AuthenticationHeaderValue: " + new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray)));

        return new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
    }
```

i just want to display a HTTPS website where authentication is needed.
i am getting a Warning from visual studio and it stop working:
An error occurred while sending the request.

´A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred in mscorlib.dll´

Comment: Is that all the Exception information?? Does it works with non HTTPS servers?

Comment: i have found, that the issue is the certificate. i have included the certificate in the app(it was invalid), now i am getting 401 Error - unauthorized. that sounds better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a more simple way to perform basic authentication.

- First create an [HttpClientHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance.
- You can set [Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.credentials%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of your HttpClientHandler instance according to your needs.
- Initialize your HttpClient using [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193664%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that accepts an HttpMessageHandler instance.

Comment: i have tried your recommendation, but now i am getting 401, unauthorized. i have updated my code, see line "This is new" comment in my code. have i forgot something?

Comment: replace  "HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();" by  "HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);" and remove "httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = CreateBasicHeader("username", "password");"

Comment: No, still does not work. i am getting the login screen in App and in console i am getting 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. how can i find out the server reqiured rules to pass correct values? maybe i am converting to wrong values..?

Comment: i have updated my code. no MD5 is needed and also no credentials used from System. now i can login and i am also getting the right response from server. i can see that in responseAsString variable. But when i call the URL in webview, i am still getting the loginscreen. i will write a new post and put the link here. thank you.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something about what you are trying to do since there is no webview in your code sample. Webview http stack shares nothing with your HttpClient. If you want to hide the basic http from your users you might need to use NavigateToString and use and URIStreamResolver to handle subsequent requests. (http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/appbuilder/archive/2013/07/17/what-s-new-in-webview-in-windows-8-1.aspx)

Comment: i want to login to a HTTPS site where the user can navigate it. The Site should be loaded in WebView. Here is my new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633366/webview-display-loginscreen-again-after-login-via-basic-authentication-with-http