# WebView display Loginscreen again after login via basic authentication with HttpClient

Tags: c#, webview, windows-runtime, dotnet-httpclient

i am connecting to a server with basic authentication and after that i am calling the URL in Webview with following code:

```
WebView.Source(new Uri("https:(//UrlHere"));
```

The Webview Puts up a Login-Window, but i am already logged in. Why is this happening?
How can i prevent this?

The way i a authenticate to the server:

```
   private async void HttpClientCall(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name + ": HTTPCLientCall entered");

    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess: " + NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess);

    //use this, for checking the network connectivity
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GetIsNetworkAvailable: " + System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable());

    //var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("GetIsNetworkAvailable: " + System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable());
    //msg.ShowAsync();


    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();


    // Assign the authentication headers
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = CreateBasicHeader("username", "password");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization: " + httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization);


    // Call out to the site
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://URLHere");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("response: " + response);
    string responseAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("response string:" + responseAsString);

    //WebViewP.Source = new Uri("https://URLHere");
}




public AuthenticationHeaderValue CreateBasicHeader(string username, string password)
{
    byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password);

    String logindata = (username + ":" + password);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AuthenticationHeaderValue: " + new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray)));

    return new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
}
```

So how can i solve that?

Comment: It is possible that the server is setting some authentication cookies.  Use fiddler and look for a set-cookies header on the server response.  If so then you could clear the cookie container to prevent being "logged in".

Comment: i dont want to prevent being "logged in". i want to keep logged in. When the httpClient is done with authorizaten, then i want to navigate/display the page. if the server sets a cookie, what i have to do? save the cookie and then call the page again? or is there another way to authorize when calling in webView?

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but you could try setting the credentials on HttpClientHandler and hope that the WebView picks it up.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username,password);
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
```

The problem is the WebView is making it's own independent request, so any requests you make with HttpClient are independent of those made by the WebView

Comment: Good day to you, sir, I am new here in C#, I have several questions about your answer and I certainly hope you'll take a minute answering them. First, there are 2 HttpClient classes since UWP, one from System namespace and another from Windows, which one were you referring to in your code snippet? Second, under what circumstances would any WebView picks that HttpClient? As far as I can tell you are just initializing a HttpClient without any mention to WebView in the code.