# HTTP Request with Basic Auth always returns 401

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to do a GET in an UWP (Windows 10) app. I've tried several ways but all always return 401.

In Postman it works fine, but I can' seem to get it to work in my app. What am I missing.

These are the methods I tried (all return 401):

Method 1:

```
        var request = WebRequest.Create("http://api.fos.be/person/login.json?login=200100593&password=pass");
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic MYAUTHTOKEN";
        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

Method 2:

```
        const string uri = "http://api.fos.be/person/login.json?login=200100593&password=pass";
        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        httpClientHandler.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MYUSERNAME", "MYPASSWORD");
        using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
        {
            var result = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            Debug.WriteLine(result.Content);

        }
```

Method 3:

```
        var client = new RestClient("http://api.fos.be/person/login.json?login=200100593&password=pass");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("postman-token", "e2f84b21-05ed-2700-799e-295f5470c918");
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic MYAUTHTOKEN");
        IRestResponse response = await client.Execute(request);
        Debug.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

The third method is code generated straight from Postman, so why is it working there and not in my app?

Comment: As @Aaron provided may be the right solution and please also confirm the `username` and `password` are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497662/how-to-use-basic-http-authentication-on-windows-rt-visual-studio-2012-c-sharp) thread helped me figure out the solution. I was using http:// but I had to make it http**s**://. HTTPS with the code in that thread was the solution.

This is my final code:

```
    public static async void GetPerson()
    {
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess: " + NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess);
        //use this, for checking the network connectivity
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GetIsNetworkAvailable: " + System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable());
        //var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("GetIsNetworkAvailable: " + System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable());
        //msg.ShowAsync();
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        // Assign the authentication headers
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = CreateBasicHeader("MYUSERNAME", "MYPASS");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization: " + httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization);
        // Call out to the site
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://api.fos.be/person/login.json?login=usern&password=pass");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("response: " + response);
        string responseAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("response string:" + responseAsString);
    }
    public static AuthenticationHeaderValue CreateBasicHeader(string username, string password)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password);
        String logindata = (username + ":" + password);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AuthenticationHeaderValue: " + new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray)));
        return new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try this first:

Check your "MYAUTHTOKEN", it is usually a combo of username:password and is base 64 encoded. So if your username was "user" and password was "pass" you would need to base64 encode "user:pass"

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.fos.be/person/login.json");
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("user:pass"));
var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it gives the following error: "A security problem occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800C000E)"

Comment: @Aaron Shouldn't `?login=200100593&password=pass` be removed when using Basic Auth?

Comment: @ThomasSchneiter, yes i would think that is unnecessary. I will edit the post accordingly.

Comment: @vixez ah, apparently the WebRequest class will not support the credentials in the uri. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Okay thanks, but the parameters are required for the server. I have found the answer meanwhile. I've posted the answer but cant accept it as answer until tomorrow. Thanks anyway.